# How to access ChartJS defaults

Tags: javascript

i need help with ChartJS v3 after migrating from v2

In v2 version i had a function that modifies ChartJS' default configuration as seen in the image below.
[configuration ChartJS v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiDah.png)

However, after migrating to ChartJS v3, i'm unable to access the default ChartJS export from the library plus my defaults do not get applied even if i modified the defaults of an already existing Chart.

Has this happened to anyone? Any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't like Screenshots. Please read the ["How do I ask?" Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it is clearly saying: " **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text." For more reasons why this deserves a downvote see http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Might be helpful: [3.x Migration Guide - chartjs.org](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out you need to import Chart and registerables, plus registering all of them in a tree-shaking approach. I had Chart2 in my project and Chart3 in my library. Using Chart3 as peerDependency and updating my project's version fixed most of the issues.